# Is it possible that onTriggerEnter2D is called for that object, but onTriggerExit2D is not called?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Objects that come into contact with each other and then fall off

Is it possible that onTriggerEnter2D is called for that object, but onTriggerExit2D is not called?

In a particular object, I save information about all the objects I contacted using OnTriggerEnter2D,

When the contact with the contacted object is over, information on the object is removed using OnTriggerExit2D

But very rarely, the removal part doesn't work
I want to know the cause of this

this is my code

```
    List<GameObject> enterObject = new List<GameObject>();

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == 8)
        {
            enterObject.Add(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == 8)
        {
            if (enterObject.Contains(collision.gameObject))
            {
                enterObject.Remove(collision.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well yes. If it never exits.